# FormState vs FormFieldState, when to use which?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently using

```
GlobalKey<FormState> state = ...;
```

And it does the job, I noticed there is another class which is `FormFieldState` which has also got same callbacks as `FormState` so I can also use

```
GlobalKey<FormFieldState> state = ...;
```

So, which one to use when, can anyone give an example demonstrating the use case of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have a Widget A containing a Form with 2 `TextFormField` and a button:

WidgetA

```
...
Column(
  children: [
    Form(
     child: Column(
       children: [
          TextFormField(...),
          TextFormField(...),
       ]
     ),
    ),
    Button(...),
  ]
)
```

and now you want to validate the Form when users press the Button. `GlobalKey<FormState> state` would be your life saver in this case as you can do like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Form(
     key: state,
     child: Column(
       children: [
          TextFormField(...),
          TextFormField(...),
       ]
     ),
    ),
    Button(
     onPressed: state.currentState.validate,
     ...,
    ),
  ]
)
```

Then imagine a `TextFormField` is having an error, and you want to reset the error in the first `TextFormField` and keep the error in the second `TextFormField`. In this case, calling `state.currentState.reset()` does not help as it will reset the whole form. Therefore, you need to use `GlobalKey<FormFieldState> firstFormFieldState`, and you can solve this problem by:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Form(
     key: state,
     child: Column(
       children: [
          TextFormField(
            key: firstFormFieldState,
            ...
          ),
          TextFormField(...),
       ]
     ),
    ),
    Button(
     onPressed: () {
       state.currentState.validate();
       firstFormFieldState.reset();
     },
     ...,
    ),
  ]
)
```

Hope it helps.